# How to delete an aptly published snapshot

Tags: 18.04

Using Ubuntu 18.04 and aptly version 1.4.0.

I am attempting to create a focal mirror using `aptly`, as follows:

```
aptly mirror create --architectures="amd64" -filter-with-deps -filter="Installed-Size (<=500000)" focal http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
aptly mirror update focal
aptly snapshot create focal-latest from mirror focal
aptly publish snapshot --skip-signing focal-latest filesystem:export:export
```

This seemed to work OK -- but I made a small mistake and want to delete the published snapshot and redo it.

How does one do this please? The command line help shows this:

```
Usage: aptly publish drop <distribution> [[<endpoint>:prefix]
```

I presume `<distribution>` is what `aptly publish snapshot` refers to as `<name>` but I have been unsuccessful divining the correct format to use. I have tried dozens of combinations, but here are a few, and the results:

```
$ aptly publish drop focal-latest
ERROR: unable to remove: published repo with storage:prefix/distribution ./focal-latest not found
$ aptly publish drop focal-latest filesystem:export:export
ERROR: unable to remove: published repo with storage:prefix/distribution filesystem:export:export/focal-latest not found
$ aptly publish drop focal-latest filesystem:export
ERROR: unable to remove: published repo with storage:prefix/distribution filesystem:export/focal-latest not found
```

Comment: I fumbled on this recently, can you please suggest how did you resolved it? Will be a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I presume `<distribution>` is what aptly publish snapshot refers to as  `<name>`

Not quite, the snapshot `<name>` is literally the snapshot name.  `<distribution>` is the repo distribution name (Aptly guesses this value from the mirror snapshot used to publish). In your case `focal`.

You can override this value when publishing. Example:

```
aptly publish snapshot -distribution=focal-latest --skip-signing focal-latest filesystem:export:export
```

The docs state for `-distribution=` param:

> "distribution name to publish; guessed from original repository distribution"

---

I am more used to using s3 and no prefix, however I think this should work for you:

```
aptly publish drop focal filesystem:export:export
```

---

Side note, you can use `aptly publish list` to give more information on your published items.